# Activity 'Result' field missing from API

Tags: api

The default field on the Activity API doesn't return 'result' field by default, or even when specified as a return value. I've never added one of these before, if someone could let me know how it's done I'll sort a PR out. Thanks!

If anyone's interested - the use case is deleting Twilio's copy of messages after a period on a scheduled job. The return value is Twilio's SMS Unique ID.

Comment: I think there is some weird logic that blocks it somewhere in the code for reasons unclear

Answer (score 2):

Api result doesn't return if the fields value is NULL. In your case result field must be **NULL** for the activity you trying to get. Try using to check if the result key is present in api result and use accordingly.

$result = CRM_Utils_Array::value('result', $activityResults);
or !empty($activityResults['result'])

[image]

HTH

Pradeep